# Timezone and locale dropdown in custom form frontend

Tags: magento2, drop-downs, locale, timezone, custom-form

I need to add these 2 dropdown to the custom frontend form.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciate. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your result by following code:

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>

<?php $localeLists = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Locale\ListsInterface'); ?>
<?php $timezones = $localeLists->getOptionTimezones(); ?>
<?php $locales = $localeLists->getOptionLocales(); ?>

<?php if(count($timezones) > 0): ?>
    <label><?= __('Timezone') ?></label>
    <select name="timezone" id="timezone">
        <?php foreach($timezones as $timezone): ?>
            <option value="<?= $timezone['value'] ?>"><?= $timezone['label'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(count($locales) > 0): ?>
    <label><?= __('Locale') ?></label>
    <select name="locale" id="locale">
        <?php foreach($locales as $locale): ?>
            <option value="<?= $locale['value'] ?>"><?= $locale['label'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Don't use objectmanager in your phtml file. Inject the **ListsInterface** class to your block construct method like below code:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\ListsInterface $localeLists,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->localeLists = $localeLists;
    ...
}

public function getTimezones()
{
    return $this->localeLists->getOptionTimezones();
}

public function getLocales()
{
    return $this->localeLists->getOptionLocales();
}
```

Now call it in phtml like below:

```
<?php $timezones = $block->getTimezones(); ?>
<?php $locales = $block->getLocales(); ?>

<?php if(count($timezones) > 0): ?>
    <label><?= __('Timezone') ?></label>
    <select name="timezone" id="timezone">
        <?php foreach($timezones as $timezone): ?>
            <option value="<?= $timezone['value'] ?>"><?= $timezone['label'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(count($locales) > 0): ?>
    <label><?= __('Locale') ?></label>
    <select name="locale" id="locale">
        <?php foreach($locales as $locale): ?>
            <option value="<?= $locale['value'] ?>"><?= $locale['label'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I achieve by this way 

<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>

<?php $localeLists = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Locale\Timezone'); ?>
<?php $timezones = $localeLists->toOptionArray(); ?> but thanks a lot for your answer